# ubuntu 12.04 freezing

Tags: nvidia, compiz

When I close Google 'Chrome (sometimes it happens with other apps) the system freezes for 5-7 seconds, even the mouse doesn't move. That problem is only with proprietary drivers. Everything's OK with nouveau. It's really annoying, what can it be?

Specs:  nvidia geforce 9500 gt (driver 295.40), Linux main 3.2.0-24-generic-pae

Comment: Have you tried the (post-release updates) driver, if so is that the same

Comment: I tried it, and I also tried drivers from nvidia PPA, but it's the same.

Comment: I am not sure you will find an answer here as it could be one of multiple things and may well be a hardware issue. I do know however that there is no particular issue with your graphics card with Ubuntu as my son has the same card and also runs Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same problem with all nvidia drivers available from Kubuntu 12.04 (64 bits) repository and most of the (latest) drivers from nvidia.
Problem seems to be at least partially solved with beta 302.11 from ftp://download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/ but BE WARNED this is an early beta driver, so YMMV.
I can use xrender, but not opengl (some artifacts are shown on screen when moving windows, etc).
My card is a GeForce 7300 LE.
If you don't want to live on the edge, use nouveau until 302.11 is out of beta stage, as it worked OK all the time (minus 3D acceleration I guess).
Good luck!

Miguel